# webhooks created in shopify but not triggered while event occurs

Tags: php, webhooks, shopify-app

I have a public app in the Shopify store I have made so many hooks as an order created, order updated, etc ... but webhook is not triggered when any of these events occur.

I created a webhook with the below PHP code while generating a token

```
 $webhookdata = array(
                    'webhook' => array(
                        'topic' => 'orders/create',
                        'address' => 'https://mydomain/order_created_webhook.php',
                        'format' => 'json',
    
                    )
                );
    
    
    $data= shopify_call($access_token, $shopName, "/admin/api/2020-01/webhooks.json", $webhookdata, 'POST');
                $data = json_decode($data['response']);
                $data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

And getting a response with below PHP code

```
ob_flush();
ob_start();
define('SHOPIFY_APP_SECRET', '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');

function verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header)
{
  $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, SHOPIFY_APP_SECRET, true));
  return hash_equals($hmac_header, $calculated_hmac);
}

$hmac_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256'];
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$verified = verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header);
echo $verified;
$data=json_decode($data);
    $myfile = file_put_contents('test.txt', ob_get_flush(), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    $myfile = file_put_contents('test.txt', ob_get_flush(), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

The problem is I am not getting any response in my text file.....